big gap and subfigure doesn't work correctly?
For some reason, when I run the code, there is a huge space at the top, and also set the width to 0.2 so that there are 5 pictures in a line, but there are 3. Why?
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
       \begin{subfigure}[!htb]{0.2\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{country A}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            %% vertices
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
            %% vertex labels
            \node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
            \node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
            \node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
            %%% edges
            \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
         \label{subfig:countryA}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{country B}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %% vertices
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
            %% vertex labels
            \node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
            \node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
            \node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
            %%% edges
            \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
         \label{subfig:countryB}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{country C}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
        %% vertices
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
        %% vertex labels
        \node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
        \node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
        \node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
        %%% edges
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
         \label{subfig:countryC}
     \end{subfigure}
     
          \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{country D}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
            %% vertices
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
            %% vertex labels
            \node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
            \node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
            \node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
            %%% edges
            \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
         \label{fsubfig:countryD}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{country E}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %% vertices
            \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
            \draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
            %% vertex labels
            \node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
            \node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
            \node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
            %%% edges
            \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
         \label{subfig:countryE}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.2\textwidth}
         \centering
         \caption{country F}
         \begin{tikzpicture}
        %% vertices
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
        %% vertex labels
        \node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
        \node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
        \node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
        %%% edges
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
         
         \label{subfig:countryF}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Trait Attacks in the Swedish Multi-Party System 1970-2022.}
    \label{fig:six_graphs}

\end{figure}
\end{document}



The optional argument of subfigure is not a floating option but a vertical alignment option. See the user manual for more information.

welcome! great to see a new contributor contribute an answerable question!

A blank line is a new paragraph, so you've explicitly asked for a paragraph break after the first three.
Moreover, an uncommented line ending is a space, so you cannot fit 5 things on a line if each is 1/5 the width of that line and there are 4 spaces, too. To avoid this, comment the line endings.

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{country A}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% vertices
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
%% vertex labels
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
\node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
\node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
%%% edges
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{subfig:countryA}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{country B}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% vertices
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
%% vertex labels
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
\node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
\node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
%%% edges
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{subfig:countryB}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{country C}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% vertices
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
%% vertex labels
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
\node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
\node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
%%% edges
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{subfig:countryC}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{country D}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% vertices
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
%% vertex labels
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
\node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
\node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
%%% edges
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fsubfig:countryD}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{country E}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% vertices
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
%% vertex labels
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
\node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
\node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
%%% edges
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{subfig:countryE}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{country F}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% vertices
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (3/2,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0.75,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
%% vertex labels
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {$v_{3}$};
\node at (1.7,-0.3) {$v_{2}$};
\node at (0.75,1.5) {$v_{1}$};
%%% edges
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (3/2,0) -- (0.75,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\label{subfig:countryF}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Trait Attacks in the Swedish Multi-Party System 1970-2022.}
\label{fig:six_graphs}

\end{figure}
\end{document}

Note that we don't comment the line ending after the fifth because we need to allow a line break there. If we comment it, TeX won't be able to break the line and will complain the line is too wide. (And the line will be too wide with the sixth subfigure sticking into the margin, at best.)

subcaption does not support options h or !hbt to subfigure, but t, b, c, T, B. It is not a float option.

@cabohah thanks. I realised that, then forgot about it, then remembered when I saw your comment on the question. strange no warning is issued on the terminal. (may be info-level, I didn't check.)

@cabohah do you know what s means (for the inner position - not the outer one - so not relevant to this example)?

stretched like the inner pos of \parbox.

@cabohah thanks.
